# Clojure: "thread-first" macro -> and "thread-last" macro ->>

Tags: clojure

I'm working on [problem #74](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/74) at 4clojure.com, the solution of mine is as following:

```
(defn FPS [s]
  (->>
    (map read-string (re-seq #"[0-9]+" s))
    (filter #(= (Math/sqrt %) (Math/floor (Math/sqrt %))))
    (interpose ",")
    (apply str)))
```

It works pretty well. But if I use the "thread-first" macro ->

```
(defn FPS [s]
  (->
    (map read-string (re-seq #"[0-9]+" s))
    (filter #(= (Math/sqrt %) (Math/floor (Math/sqrt %))))
    (interpose ",")
    (apply str)))
```

It returns: `ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.core/apply (core.clj:617)`

Why can "->>" not be replaced by "->" in this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Clojure REPL:

```
user=> (doc ->)
-------------------------
clojure.core/->  
([x & forms])
Macro   
 Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
 second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
 list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the


 user=> (doc ->>)
 -------------------------
 clojure.core/->>
 ([x & forms])
  Macro   
  Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  last item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  last item in second form, etc.
```

`filter` function expects the first argument to be a function, not a sequence and by using S`->` , you are not satisfying its requirement.

That is why you are getting `clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn` exception in your code.

Answer (score 10):

Thread-last macro (`->>`) inserts each for as the *last* element of the next form. Thread-first macro (`->`) inserts it as the *second* element.

So, this:

```
(->> a
     (b 1)
     (c 2))
```

translates to: `(c 2 (b 1 a))`, while

```
(-> a
    (b 1)
    (c 2))
```

translates to: `(c (b a 1) 2)`.

Comment: `->` inserts at the second position, not the first.